# 2D array of 2 cells lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to implement a minesweeper so I have a 2d array, where each cell holds `['H', ' ']`.

When I try to update the second value in a selected rowXcol it updates all values in the array and not only the selected.
i.e:

```
  0 1 2 3
0        
1        
2        
3
```

```
myArr[1][2][1] = 'x'
```

```
  0 1 2 3
0 x x x x
1 x x x x 
2 x x x x
3 x x x x
```

instead of :

```
  0 1 2 3
0        
1     x
2
3
```

Comment: This has to do with the way you created `myArr`. You probably did something like `[['H', ' '] * N] * N`. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16531580/1258041) and other questions about creation of nested lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create your 2D nested list like this:

```
lines = 4
cols  = 4
a = [[['H',' '] for j in range(cols)] for i in range(lines)]
```

You will not have this problem.